# How to rename an index in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In other databases such as MySQL I could just do this:

```
ALTER TABLE demo RENAME INDEX old_index TO new_index
```

What's the best workaround for SQLite?

**Update**

SQLite does not seem to support this syntax. In which case is there a work around I can use. For example:

```
DROP INDEX old_index;
CREATE INDEX new_index ON demo(col1, col2);
```

The issue with the above is that I need to manually find out which columns were indexed. I want something that can be done automatically like:

```
set columns = select columns indexed by old_index;
DROP INDEX old_index;
CREATE INDEX new_index ON demo(columns);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQLite's ALTER TABLE does not support this. Just recreate it:

```
DROP INDEX old_index;
CREATE INDEX new_index ON demo([...]);
```

You can get the index definition from the schema:

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'index' AND name = 'old_index';
```

But there is no mechanism to modify and execute the result from inside SQLite.

Comment: In that case, is there a way to determine what column/s the index was originally on using SQL?